# Remotebuild Cordova Windows -> iOS : Get list of devices

Tags: ios, cordova

We're developing a Cordova app on Windows, and are deploying it to iOS using remotebuild. Everything works fine. 
We need to deploy to multiple Android and iOS devices for releases. Right now this involves doing one at a time. 
I've already created a script to retrieve all Android devices, which works great.

However, how can I get a list of iOS devices from my Windows machine? If I run "cordova run --list" I only get the Android devices, for the iOS devices I get the following error:

```
platforms\ios\cordova\lib\list-devices' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

As this script is obviously an iOS script.

How can I use the remote build server to get a list of devices? When I browse to http://mac-ip:3000 I get a welcome screen:

```
Remote build Express server open for business on port 3000
```

As it's all web based, is there a URL I can access to retrieve a list of devices?

Comment: The command works fine on mac. File an issue on issues.cordova.io, so cordova team can look into it

Comment: Yes it works fine on mac, but I want to run it from Windows...

Comment: I don't think you can,  file an issue on issues.cordova.io, so cordova team can look into it